# R: Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "1") : invalid factor level, NA generated

Tags: r

A partir de un data.frame como este:
            WMV_positive_data:

```
             Habitat          ID          SPP         Family
              Crop           M1V13    Cucumis_melo         Cucurbitaceae
              Crop           m1v14    Amaranthus_sp        Amaranthaceae
              Crop           M1V16    Convolvulus_arvensis Convolvulaceae
              Crop           M2V26    Solanum_nigrum       Solanaceae
              Crop           M3V37    Chenopodium_album    Chenopodiaceae
              Crop           m3v41    Lithospermum_arvense Boraginaceae
              Edge           L2P24    Carduus_bourgeanus   Asteraceae
              Edge           L2V14    Picris_echioides     Asteraceae
              Edge           L2V4     Conyza_canadensis    Asteraceae
              Edge           L3F33    Cynodon_dactylon     Poaceae
              Edge           L3P2     Diplotaxis_erucoides Brassicaceae
```

Realizo una matriz con esta función:

```
    WMV_positive_data.matrix<- acast(WMV_positive_data, Habitat ~ Spp , fill = 0); head(WMV_positive_data.matrix); dim(WMV_positive_data.matrix)

   rownames(WMV_positive_data.matrix)
```

y obtengo la siguiente advertencia:

```
   Warning message:
   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(ordered), value = 0) :
   invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Posteriormente intento realizar la siguiente función:

```
 modify.WMV_positive_data.matrix<-replace(WMV_positive_data.matrix,WMV_positive_data.matrix!="0","1")
```

y me sigue saliendo el mismo valor:

```
 Warning message:
 In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "1") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esa advertencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrián, el problema seguramente es que al importar el archivo, las variables de `WMV_positive_data` se han definido como factores. Podemos reproducir el problema así:

```
library(reshape2)

WMV_positive_data <- read.table(text="
Habitat        ID       Spp                  Family
Crop           M1V13    Cucumis_melo         Cucurbitaceae
Crop           m1v14    Amaranthus_sp        Amaranthaceae
Crop           M1V16    Convolvulus_arvensis Convolvulaceae
Crop           M2V26    Solanum_nigrum       Solanaceae
Crop           M3V37    Chenopodium_album    Chenopodiaceae
Crop           m3v41    Lithospermum_arvense Boraginaceae
Edge           L2P24    Carduus_bourgeanus   Asteraceae
Edge           L2V14    Picris_echioides     Asteraceae
Edge           L2V4     Conyza_canadensis    Asteraceae
Edge           L3F33    Cynodon_dactylon     Poaceae
Edge           L3P2     Diplotaxis_erucoides Brassicaceae", header==TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
WMV_positive_data.matrix <- acast(WMV_positive_data, Habitat ~ Spp , fill = 0)


Using Family as value column: use value.var to override.
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(ordered), value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Revisa como estás importando el archivo, seguramente tengas que definir el parámetro `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` para que las variables sean solo caracteres. Sino, puedes transformar todos los factores de la siguiente manera:

```
WMV_positive_data <- as.data.frame(lapply(WMV_positive_data, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Más allá de esto que te comento, me llama la atención como estás usando `acast`, sin indicar ninguna función de agregación, si lo que buscas es quedarte con una matriz que te indique `1` y `0` podrías hacer algo así:

```
acast(WMV_positive_data, Habitat ~ Spp, function(x) as.numeric(length(x) > 0))
```

Esto no tiene inconvenientes con factores y creo que es más directo. Sino, con una  una tabla de contingencia podría ser así:

```
ifelse(table(WMV_positive_data[, c(1,3)])>0,1,0)
```